# c# class inherits from base class with constructor with dependency injection

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a project using `Dependency Injection` (Ninject) where I have the following class:

```
public class SecurityService : BaseService
    {
        ISecurityRepository _securityRepo = null;

        public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo)
        {
            _securityRepo = securityRepo;
        }
}
```

Because `BaseService` is going to be referenced in many other service classes I wanted to add there a method that also go to Data Repository and get some information so I don't have to repeat the same code along the other service classes.

Here is what I have for `BaseRepository`:

```
public partial class BaseService
    {

        IEntityRepository _entityRepo = null;

        public BaseService(IEntityRepository entityRepo)
        {
            _entityRepo = entityRepo;
        }

         public Settings AppSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return _entityRepo.GetEntitySettings();
            }
        }
}
```

But when I compile I get the following error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'entityRepo' of 'BaseService.BaseService(IEntityRepository)'
```

[image]

And the error make sense because now I have a constructor that I guess is expecting something.

> Any clue how to fix this but that I can still have my dependency injection in `BaseRepository` class?

**UPDATE**

I just tried to remove the constructor and use the attribute `[Inject]` but when debugging I see that `_entityRepo` is `NULL`.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, don't you need to call BaseService constructor in SecurityService ? Something like `public BaseService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo, IEntityRepository entityRepo) : base(securityRepo)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dependency to the constructor for the derived class, and pass it along.

```
public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo, IEntityRepository entityRepo)
    : base(entityRepo) 
{
    _securityRepo = securityRepo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could make it work:

I just convert the private property to be public and then `[Inject]` attribute started to work.

```
public partial class BaseService
    {
        [Inject]
        public IEntityRepository EntityRepo { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Repository object to the base class via the child class constructor:

```
public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo) : base(IEntityRepository)
{
  //Initialize stuff for the child class
}
```